# Puppet - remove ini_setting completely

Tags: puppet, manifest, ini

I am using puppet 4.5.3 and ini_setting module version 1.4.2. I need to be able to remove a stanza in an ini file. For example:

```
[header]
ip = '1.1.1.1'
hostname = 'myserver'
port = 80
```

I am able to remove each section of the ini file using the `ensure => absent` parameter but I cannot find a way to remove the stanza header, or preferably the whole thing in one command.

What I have left is

```
[header]
```

Does anyone know how this can be done? Unfortunately there are other stanzas in the same file that I need to keep so I cannot simply delete the file.

thanks,

Comment: You may have better luck with augeas for removing large parts of files including headers: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/resources_augeas.html. Does that look appealing to you?

Comment: this is my last attempt at success before i succumb to the craziness that is augeas :(

Comment: I don't particularly care for augeas either, but it probably is your best option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Augeas type:

```
augeas { 'remove_ini_header':
  incl    => '/etc/example.ini',
  lens    => 'IniFile.lns_loose',
  changes => 'rm section[. = "header"]',
}
```

To break this down a bit, first I used the built-in `IniFile.lns_loose` lens (i.e. a "generic" loose parsing of INI files) and `augtool` to see the current state of the tree:

```
$ augtool -t "IniFile.lns_loose incl /etc/example.ini"
augtool> print /files/etc/example.ini
/files/etc/example.ini
/files/etc/example.ini/section = "header"
/files/etc/example.ini/section/ip = "'1.1.1.1'"
/files/etc/example.ini/section/hostname = "'myserver'"
/files/etc/example.ini/section/port = "80"
```

The entire section is in one part of the tree, so calling `rm` for that section will delete the entire subtree.

To match the header section, you need to search for nodes called `section` where the value (the right hand side) is `header`. The `[. = "header"]` part of the command is a [path expression](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/wiki/Path-expressions) that filters for nodes with the value `header`.